# Attach to unattached session, or create new session: not quite what "new -A" does

Tags: tmux

I have a shell alias:

```
ssh -A -t hostname tmux new -A
```

this mostly does what I want.  If there's an existing session on the remote host, it attaches to it.  If there's no session, it creates a new one.  This is exactly what I want most of the time, so I can get back to sessions orphaned by network failures.

The problem comes up when I occasionally want to open two session to the same host from different windows.  When I run that command in the second window, it sees the existing session and attaches to it.  I now have two windows attached to the same session.  What I really want is:

```
If there's a *detached* session, attach to it
Else, create a new session.
```

Is this possible?  If it matters, my desktop is MacOS and all my target hosts are Debian Linux.  And I run with

```
set-option -g prefix None
```

in my .tmux.conf file.

Comment: what do you want it to do if there are already 2 attached sessions?

Comment: Make a new one.

Comment: please update your question by clarifying this.